# Feynman diagram: overlapping momenta and arrows

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman

I have the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikZ-feynman}
\use[ackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram
[horizontal=d to f1] {
% Draw the top and bottom lines
i1 [particle=\(\nu\)] -- [draw=none] a  ,
i2 [particle=\(\mu\)] -- [draw=none] c-- [fermion, momentum'=\(q\mathord-p_2\)] d,
d -- [fermion, momentum'=\(q\mathord+p_1\)] a,
d --[scalar, momentum'=\({p_1\mathord+p_2}\)] f1,
i2 -- [gluon, momentum'=\(k_2\)] a,
i1 -- [gluon, momentum'=\(k_1\)] c,
i1 -- [draw=none] i2,
% Draw the two internal fermion lines
{ [  same layer
] a -- [fermion, momentum'=\(l\)] c },
{ %[  same layer] b -- [anti fermion,edge label=\(\nu_{\mu}\)] d
}
};

\end{document}
```

But on my end I get this:

[image]

The shape is clearly not ideal. That aside, I would like to display the momentum $l$ on the other side of the propagator, and disentangle the mess that is the momenta of $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Comment: Could you make a mock-up of how you want the result to look (either by editing your screenshot in a bitmap graphics editor like MS Paint or by making a sketch on paper)? Otherwise good question, +1.

Comment: There is no need to use `momentum'` for all momenta. If you drop the prime, the momentum will be on the other side. If you do this for the `l` momentum (use `\ell`, please!) things look already less cramped, similarly for `k_2`. Then your document misses the `\documentclass` and the definition of `\mo`, and when one fixes these, the output looks very different, the gluons lines do not cross. Please provide a compilable code.

Comment: Please can you add a hand-drawing of your picture?